# Font Awesome Does Not Show

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have included font-awesome at my project and I tried these two icons:

```
<a href="" class="fa fa-eye text-dark"></a>
<a href="" class="fa fa-wallet text-dark"></a>
```

The eye icon appears but the wallet icon does not appear somehow.

I also tried `fas fa-wallet text-dark` but didn't show the icon.

So how to load the icon correctly.

Comment: are you using the V5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below font awesome script into the head tag and then load the icon

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```html
<a href="" class="fas fa-wallet text-dark"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download or link to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of FA you are using. In the past, this type of issue has driven me nuts. "Why is one icon loading but not the other?" Older versions of FA won't include newer icons. So they won't appear.